# Load current from two lithium-ion parallel cells

Tags: current, lithium-ion, cell-balancing

How do I calculate the current flowing from V2 into V1?

I have two lithium-ion cells that are connected in parallel to a load R3. Let's say R3 draws 200 A.

How much current will flow through NODE 1 and NODE 2 (NODE 2 will be the current flowing at NODE 1 + the current from V2)?

Secondly, will V2 start to balance V1? If so, does this mean the current will flow from V2 to V1 and also R3? If so, how much current will it be?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7KhbI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is a button to simulate that circuit you drew. It shows Cell 2 provides about 195 A and Cell 1 about 5 A. With load both cells discharge. With no load about 2.7 A flows between cells.

Comment: @Justme why doesn't 2.7A also flow from V2 to V1 when a load is connected?

Comment: Because the voltage at Node 2 will be lower than both V1 and V2. All the current will flow into R3.